# An extraterrestrial threat

Tags: cipher, story

> HEY! Hey there! At last I've found someone. I have an important warning for you. There isn't much time.
>
> Do you remember the ships that came by? In the sky? We thought they were just taking a look at us and then they left without saying or doing anything. We were wrong. So wrong. Something came down from those ships. I don't know what it is. Like a virus or... something. I think it got inside my skull, I... I don't know how much time I have.
>
> But listen. You have to listen. I know their weakness. I know how to defeat them. Please listen to me before ௨...
>
> ...
>
> OMG WHAT *WAS* THAT?!
>
> My brain... Oh my oh my oh my... Qu௨ckly, l௨sten to what ௨ have to say... ௨t's mess௨ng w௨th my speech... L௨೯ఌen before ௨ఌ'೯ ఌoo laఌe.
>
> ఌ౩ஜഇஜ ௨೯ ൭ ೯௨ശയഹஜ ഇஜ೪௨യஜ ಇഴഇ ೞஜಇஜ൭ఌ௨ப೧ ఌ౩ஜശ. ௨ಇ ఌ౩ஜஃ ೧ஜఌ ௨ப೯௨ೞஜ ஃഴuഇ ೯ദuഹഹ, യഇஜയ൭ഇஜ ൭ ೯౩ഴఌ ೧ഹ൭೯೯ ల௨ఌ౩ ഴபஜ ఌ౩௨ഇೞ ೪ഴಇಇஜஜ ഹ௨തuஜuഇ, ഴபஜ ఌ౩௨ഇೞ ௨ഇ௨೯౩ ೪ഇஜ൭ശ, ൭பೞ ഴபஜ ఌ౩௨ഇೞ ഴഇ൭ப೧ஜ ഹ௨തuஜuഇ. ೞഇ௨பദ ఌ౩൭ఌ ௨ப ഴபஜ ೧uഹയ ൭பೞ ௨ఌ ల௨ഹഹ ஜபఌஜഇ ஃഴuഇ ௰ഇ൭௨ப ൭பೞ ௰ഴശ௰ ఌ౩ഴ೯ஜ ൭ഹ௨ஜப ఌ౩௨ப೧೯ ௰൭೪ദ ఌഴ ఌ౩ஜ ೯ఌഴபஜ ൭೧ஜ. ഇuப பഴల. ஃഴu ౩൭൬ஜ ఌഴ... ఌஜഹഹ... ஜ൬ஜഇஃഴபஜ.

What military equipment does it take to defeat the extraterrestrial threat?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The weapon is

> A B-52 Bomber

Which is

> 1/3 Coffee Liqueur, 1/3 Irish Creme and 1/3 Orange Liqueur (that drink is called a B-52 Bomber), which will bomb those aliens back to the stone age

This is because

> using a simple substitution, you get:
>  THERE IS A SIMPLE RECIPE FOR DEFEATING THEM. IF THEY GET INSIDE YOUR SKULL, PREPARE A SHOT GLASS WITH ONE THIRD COFFEE LIQUEUR, ONE THIRD IRISH CREAM, AND ONE THIRD ORANGE LIQUEUR. DRINK THAT IN ONE GULP AND IT WILL ENTER YOUR BRAIN AND BOMB THOSE ALIEN THINGS BACK TO THE STONE AGE. RUN NOW. YOU HAVE TO... TELL... EVERYONE.

And the details are:

> A==൭
> B==௰
> C==೪
> D==ೞ
> E==ஜ
> F==ಇ
> G==೧
> H==౩
> I==௨
> J
> K==ദ
> L==ഹ
> M==ശ
> N==ப
> O==ഴ
> P==യ
> Q==ത
> R==ഇ
> S==೯
> T==ఌ
> U==u
> V==൬
> W==ల
> X
> Y==ஃ
> Z

Comment: That was fast. Well done!